# How to add custom simple URL to Liferay site?

Tags: url, liferay

Is it possible to make URLs like `mysite/business` work?

Default page friendly URL is `mysite/web/mypage`.

Can I make it shorter for some pages?

Comment: you can use friend-url routes for tidying up the urls or make a configuration in ROOT's `web.xml` for URLRewriteFilter based on url pattern.

Comment: How to utilize first solution?

Comment: I realized, that using `friendly-url-routes.xml` is only possible with a portlet and not with a page (`Layout`). So you are left with using [URLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on [Virtual Hosts](http://www.naelshawwa.com/liferay-virtual-hosting-friendly-urls-2/)

They can help replacing the 'web/guest' url part
Then, use Friendly Urls to shorten the url part after the '~', and hide the bulky [portlet Instance]-[attribute-name]=[value] parameters